Individual data dump filenames should contain the dates they were generated
Historically, the data dumps hosted by clearbits or the internet archive were a single, monolithic 'set', and having a single datestamp for the collection made sense.
With the current system you're downloading a single file per site - and that changes the process and dynamic of how people would consume the files.
While there's ways for folks to get the whole collection of files, with individual files/downloads per site, it could get messy for someone wanting to maintain a set of 'historical' dumps for one or more files.
The download page currently contains a "Last uploaded" date. Would it be possible to include this as a timestamp in the filename of the .7z file?

People are writing new automation, and that its a bit tricky to keep track of multiple dumps is a complaint I've heard of before. - and I'm open to other approaches, just wonder if there's a way to include this in the files somewhere for ease of use
